# Eloquent haversine formula is not working as expected

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, haversine

I got stuck with the haversine formula which in my case still does not work.

In the following example, I get users and all their relationships. I need to retrieve users based on the distance from the searched address. With the instructions below I get the following error: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'distance' in 'having clause'

"activity_latitude" and "activity_longitude" are both stored in the main user table from which I start to get the data. What I'm doing wrong?

```
$q = self->whereNull("deleted_at")->where("group_id", 1)
        ->with([
            "data", 
            "rating",
            "pendingcontents",
            "openinghours",
            "openinghours.dayofweek",
            "openinghoursexceptions",
            "isopeningtime",
            "contents",
            "contents.translation", 
        ]);

$q->selectRaw('( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) *
                cos( radians( activity_latitude ) )
                * cos( radians( activity_longitude ) - radians(?)
                ) + sin( radians(?) ) *
                sin( radians( activity_latitude ) ) )
                ) AS distance', [$geocodedAddress[0], $geocodedAddress[1], $geocodedAddress[0]])
->havingRaw("distance < ?", [$radius]);
```

Then I need also to order by distance.

**To sum up**, I just need to take based on the distance and sort by distance.

I don't understand why this version works... using a related table and its coordinates

```
$q->whereHas('businessdata', function ($q) use ($filtro, $geocodedAddress, $radius) {
                $q->selectRaw('( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) *
                    cos( radians( activity_latitude ) )
                    * cos( radians( activity_longitude ) - radians(?)
                    ) + sin( radians(?) ) *
                    sin( radians( activity_latitude ) ) )
                    ) AS distance', [$geocodedAddress[0], $geocodedAddress[1], $geocodedAddress[0]])
                ->havingRaw("distance < ?", [$radius]);
            });
```

Comment: @thmsdnnr This though [works in MySQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=a4f9e81fb8c2c80b9af4e05ed2cd1130)

Comment: @thmsdnnr I suppose it would take 2 seconds to check :-(

Comment: If it was me, I'd create a sproc for calculating the distance, and then call it twice - once in the SELECT clause and again in a WHERE clause. It may seem counterintuitive, but I suspect that this is faster than calling the alias in a HAVING clause. If performance is critical, then you can also look at creating a bounding box, but this is discussed elsewhere.

Comment: Indeed... thanks for the correction! (deleted mistaken comment above that MySQL doesn't allow for an alias in a HAVING clause, like MS SQL).

Comment: @thmsdnnr Feel free to delete misleading comments.

Comment: I guess your SELECT clause is overwritten somewhere later in your code.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I tried to remove every instruction after that but nothing still works. I edited the example and added a solution that works (but I don't need it, since I don't need the coordinates of the related table)

Answer (score 0):

You have an alias assigned (distance).

You can simply use `orderBy()` from

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset

This will allow you to use the distance alias. i.e.

```
$q->selectRaw('( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) *
                cos( radians( activity_latitude ) )
                * cos( radians( activity_longitude ) - radians(?)
                ) + sin( radians(?) ) *
                sin( radians( activity_latitude ) ) )
                ) AS distance', [$geocodedAddress[0], $geocodedAddress[1], $geocodedAddress[0]])
->havingRaw("distance < ?", [$radius])
->orderBy("distance");
```

You can also pass a second optional parameter for direction (default is 'asc').

Comment: But there's another problem to solve before: column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'distance' in 'having clause' - it seems that the distance alias does not exists or is interpreted as the name of a column. What I need is just to get by distance and order by distance

Comment: try swapping your havingRaw() for a where. having is used for filtering groups, whilst where is used for filtering rows. From your query, it seems you aren't grouping anything before filtering?

Comment: I used a where but still the same problem... distance does not exist